# Adding Custom Enums in Visual Studio Code

Tags: enums, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code, is it possible to create custom ENUMS or Constants which will be highlighted in the editor?

For example, when the user types **IN_JUMP** when they are coding in lua, am I able to make this text highlighted or a different colour to indicate it is a valid ENUM?

Comment: I am creating a plugin, so if the only method is through creating a plugin, that option is open to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like semantic highlighting, which is not supported yet. There is an open feature request for it: [#585](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/585)

What you *can* do with [`tmLanguage`](https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars) grammar files (which is what VSCode uses) is highlight based on naming conventions - you could for instance give a different scope to `UPPER_CASE` identifiers. However, then you still need the used theme to color that scope differently.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. Hopefully this feature will come soon!